# How to add chart and data with HTML2PDF?

Tags: javascript, charts, flot, html2pdf

I am working on report pages where lots of data are reported in 2 manners. 1 Table manner and 2 Pie chart or Data Chart manner based on report. Now customer wants to convert it to PDF to easily export it. With help of HTML2PDF library i was able to convert normal HTML data to PDF but when dynamic charts are created, it creates problem. Here is my code i have made it but it is not working for PDF generation for chart.

```html
$content = " FULL HTML Content from template file";
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libs/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $script = "<script src='".$config['js']."'jquery.min.js'></script>
                <script src='".$config['js']."'pages/chart_reports.js'></script>
                <script src='".$config['js_common']."'flot/jquery.flot.min.js'></script>
                <script src='".$config['js_common']."'flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js'></script>";

    $script1 = "var d1 = [];";

    for($i=0;$i<count($rpt_data);$i++)
    {
        $script1 .= "d1.push(['".$rpt[$i]['grade']."}',".$rpt[$i]['grade_count']."]);";
    }
    $script1 .= "
    $.plot('#placeholder', [ d1 ], {
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.6,
                        align: 'center'
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: 'categories',
                    tickLength: 0
                }
            });";
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
    $html2pdf->pdf->IncludeJS($script);
    $html2pdf->pdf->IncludeJS($script1);
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content,$_GET['vuehtml']);
    $html2pdf->Output($fullPath,'D');
```

Can anyone let me know how to include chart in PDF with this library? Also if  this library do not support any other library which works?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution>